# Unknown prop `selectable` on <table> tag. in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, material-ui

I am getting an error when adding **selectable** attribute into Table of Material Ui with React Js. 
Why is this happening. I checked **selectable** is there in TableProps.

**My Dependencies :**

"material-ui": "1.0.0-beta.41",

"react": "15.6.1"

Comment: Where did you find ```selectable``` in the TableProps? It is not mentioned in the [docs](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/table/)

Comment: I can see this selectable property  in Table properties http://www.material-ui.com/v0.16.0/#/components/table

Comment: As you can see in the url it is the documentation of material-ui version 0.16.0

Comment: Thanks @AnikoLitvanyi , I thought since 1.0.0-beta.41 released 9 days ago and 0.20 was older than this beta.  This 0.20 features should be there too. thanks for pointing out this. 
If i use 0.20 i can get this feature, isn't. ?

Comment: But I can see them in C:\UserFolder\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\2.7\node_modules\@types\material-ui\index.d.ts
When i see definition  of Table

Comment: this is not used in the newer version because the typings are now built-in

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Table/Table.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

You are passing that prop to `<table>` not [`<Table>`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table).